# Host machine unable to communicate to Vagrant (nginx) on port 81

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, server, vagrant

how can I make my Host machine (Windows 10) to display my test site hosted on my Vagrant (Ubuntu 14.04). When I'm trying to do a ***curl localhost.ng:81*** on Ubuntu I can see it displays the nginx default page but when trying to access ***localhost.ng:81*** or ***localhost.ng:8100*** on my host machine (Windows) it displays ***This webpage is not available***. Below are my configurations

Windows etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.0.25 localhost.ng
```

Vagrant file network config:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 81, host: 8100
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.25"
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Nginx vhost config:

```
server {
        listen 81 default_server;
        listen [::]:81 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /development/nginx/sites;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost.ng;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            autoindex on;
        }

        #error_page 404 /404.html;
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #root /development/nginx/sites;
        #}

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

/etc/hosts config:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.2 localhost.ng

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1 developer developer
```

Logs:

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
    default: Adapter 3: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 81 (guest) => 8100 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
```

Files under /development/nginx/sites are set 777 mode and owned by www:data since this is just for testing. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: One thing for sure, you shouldn't be setting up the `private_network` IP address with the same value as your host machine. You end up with two machines having the same IP. Whether this is preventing the port forwarding is hard to tell, it might behave randomly in such case.

Comment: @techraf thank you, I just found out that the IP I'm using on my virtual machine is not in the IP range of my host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a in you varant configuration `private_network` the IP to be used in vagrant should be in the IP range of the host machine.